# Only allow one to one mapping between two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two column dataframe df, each row are distinct, one element in one column can map to one or more than one elements in another column. I want to filter OUT those elements. So in the final dataframe, one element in one column only map to a unique element in another column.

What I am doing is to groupby one column and count the duplicates, then remove rows with counts more than 1. and do it again for another column. I am wondering if there is a better, simpler way.

Thanks

---

edit1: I just realize my solution is INCORRECT, removing multi-mapping elements in column A reduces the number of mapping in column B, consider the following example:

A   B

1   4

1   3

2   4

1 maps to 3,4 , so the first two rows should be removed, and 4 maps to 1,2. The final table should be empty. However, my solution will keep the last row.

Can anyone provide me a fast and simple solution ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, You could do something like the following:

```
>>> df

   A  B
0  1  4
1  1  3
2  2  4
3  3  5
```

You only want to keep a row if no other row has the value of 'A' and no other row as that value of 'B'. Only row three meets those conditions in this example:

```
>>> Aone = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
>>> Bone = df.groupby('B').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
>>> Aone.merge(Bone,on=['A','B'],how='inner')

    A  B
 0  3  5
```

Explanation:

```
>>> Aone = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
>>> Aone

   A  B
2  2  4
3  3  5
```

The above grabs the rows that may be allowed based on looking at column 'A' alone.

```
>>> Bone = df.groupby('B').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
>>> Bone

   A  B
1  1  3
3  3  5
```

The above grabs the rows that may be allowed based on looking at column 'B' alone. And then merging the intersection leaves you with rows that only meet both conditions:

```
>>> Aone.merge(Bone,on=['A','B'],how='inner')
```

Note, you could also do a similar thing using `groupby/transform`. But transform tends to be slowish so I didn't do it as an alternative.

Comment: Yes, I did it with groupby/transform. thanks for your answer, I always wonder which one I should use. For example, I always like to use something like .apply() because it is very general, and powerful, but might be slow. Thanks!